# Some question about the async function with express JS NodeJS and Mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a problem with the async function with express JS  NodeJS and Mongo db.

I created an api call function for the user use the "student id" to find their record.
I have a problem when the async function to find the user._id
the api call would display the result faster than async function return the value.

Result would return the value as undefined.

API Router code:

```
router.get('/user_record/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const sid = await getIdByStudentId(req.params.id)
        console.log("----- res : " + sid)
        res.json({"id": sid})

    }catch (err){
        console.log("check- 2")
        res.json({message: err})
    }
})


//Function
function getIdByStudentId(sid){
    console.log("input id: " + sid)
    const student =  User.find({studentid:sid }).exec().then(function (results){
        if(results.length > 0) {
            const studentId =  results[0]._id
            console.log("get Id: " + studentId)
            return results[0]._id
        }else{
            return ""
        }
    })
}
```

Schema

```
const userSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    studentid:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    
    username:{
        type:String,
    },
    
    gender:{
        type:String,
    },
    ...
    createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now
    },

  
})
```

API call

```
http://XXXX.com/user_record/4
```

The console log Return

```
input id: 4 //<-- Log at async function 
res : undefined //<--- Log at api call  
get Id: 608915308462c0ccec435a97 // <--- Log at async function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `getIdByStudentId()` function is not returning anything at all.

Let's re-arrange your code. You have this:

```
function getIdByStudentId(sid){
    console.log("input id: " + sid);
    const student = User.find({studentid:sid }).exec().then(something);
}
```

and this:

```
function something(results) {
    if (results.length > 0) {
        const studentId = results[0]._id;
        console.log("get Id: " + studentId);
        return results[0]._id;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

When you look at the code from this angle, would you expect that the `return` statement inside of `something()` has any effect on the return value of `getIdByStudentId()`? I didn't think so.

What you actually wanted to write is:

```
function getIdByStudentId(sid) {
    return User.findOne({studentid: sid}).exec().then( (result) => result ? result._id : "" );
}
```

Note the `return`. Also, `.findOne()`  is defined as *["returns a single document, or `null`"](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)*. That's a better fit than `.find()`.

Usage would be exactly as you already have it:

```
router.get('/user_record/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const sid = await getIdByStudentId(req.params.id);
        res.json({id: sid});
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was 
not sure when to return value on my function.

Comment: @NapoleonWaiLunWong You can't return the value in an asynchronous function. You can return the *promise* for the value. That's what my function does. Waiting for the promise to resolve is the caller's responsibility. That's what the `await` in your route handler does.